# Custom marker not showing on Google Map

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have added Google map and try to change the marker to my own custom one. It seems not displaying it. below is the code:

```
mapFragment?.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
        if(location != null) {
            googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
                val bounds = LatLngBounds.builder()
                bounds.include(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude ))
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude ), 15.0f))
                googleMap.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions()
                        .position(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude ))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
                            createCustomMarker(requireContext(), R.drawable.pin, name)))
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

and the associated code is:

```
private fun createCustomMarker(context: Context, @DrawableRes resource: Int, _name: String?): Bitmap {

    val marker = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.new_marker, null)

    val markerImage: ImageView =
        marker.findViewById<View>(R.id.image) as ImageView
    markerImage.setImageResource(resource)
    val txt_name = marker.findViewById<View>(R.id.name) as TextView
    txt_name.text = _name
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    (context as Activity).windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    marker.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(52, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    marker.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels)
    marker.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels)
  //  marker.buildDrawingCache()
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        marker.measuredWidth,
        marker.measuredHeight,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    marker.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

the xml layout is pretty basic:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/marker_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    tools:text="name"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_pin"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Any idea why the marker is not showing up in the map ?

Thanks

Comment: did you get an answer?